# Fonts similar to Andika and Lexie-Readable?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I have dyslexia but the regular dyslexic fonts don't work out for me. Andika and Lexie-Readable are much better for me, and I was wondering if there's anything similar.

Answer (score 2):

My daughter has dyslexia, so this is a topic close to my heart! You may want to reach out to these folks - https://www.omoguru.com/dyslexia-friendly-font-system/  They produce an app and chrome plugin utilizing their font family, but it looks like you can contact them to try out their font for free for personal use.